# how to retrive data from database and add it to textview?.That is similar to adding data to listview

Tags: android, android-sqlite, textview

I am trying to add data from `DbHandler.java` to `textView` in `MainActivity.java.`
i hava already done a similar project adding data to `listView` using `List<String>`
now i want to do it for `textView`

My MainActivity.java code to populate list view:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    String loc = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    DbHandler db = new DbHandler(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> BusNoListUsingLoc = db.getBusNoUsingLoc(loc);
    ArrayAdapter<String> lvAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, BusNoListUsingLoc);
    listView.setAdapter(lvAdapter);

}
```

My DbHandler.java:

```
 public List<String> getBusNoUsingLoc(String loc)
{
    List<String> BusRouteList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] cols={"From_Loc","To_Loc","Route_1","Route_2","Route_3","Route_4","Route_5","Route_6","Route_7","Route_8","Route_9","Route_10","Route_11","Route_12","Route_13","Route_14","Route_15"};
        String query="SELECT Bus_No_Type FROM MDUBusRoutes WHERE";
        for (int i=0;i<cols.length;i++)
        {
            if(i!=cols.length-1)
                query+=" UPPER(" + cols[i] + ")= UPPER(?) OR";
            else
                query+=" UPPER(" + cols[i] + ")= UPPER(?) ORDER BY Total_Stops DESC";
        }
        Cursor CursorLocationRoute = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc,loc});
        if (CursorLocationRoute.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                BusRouteList.add(CursorLocationRoute.getString(0));
            }
            while (CursorLocationRoute.moveToNext());
        }
        CursorLocationRoute.close();
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored)
    {

    }
    return BusRouteList;
}
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYqy6.jpg)

Comment: Previously i have used this code only(ListView only) now i want to display datas in textview @Barns52

Comment: Please explain in more detail how your final result will appear on your activity. For example: do you want to programmatically create a `TextView` for each value in your `List<String> BusRouteList` or do you want to `concat` them into one string and display them in a single `TextView`?

Comment: I have added a image in that when location:Mattuthavani it shows bus number(Starting in 3 DLX) in listview.now i want to display the numbers in textview programmatically @Barns52

Comment: Are these `TextView` objects inside the `ListView`?

Comment: No.i will remove the listView and add textView instead if it after getting solution.i have no idea about populating textview from database so i still didn't try any code for that @Barns52

Comment: Maximum number of entries in `List<String>` is 20 @Barns52

Comment: Does the number of entries vary -- sometime less or more?

Comment: Yes,it will change when `AutoCompleteTextView` item is changed @Barns52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you will be better served by a `ListView` because it scrolls when needed, it keeps your rows nice and consistent and it basically takes care of any variable length entries you have, but if you really want to do this with `TextView`s then try this:

(If you need to scroll, because the numbers of entries is so large that your `TextView`s no long fit on the screen, then you will need to put the `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`.)

Put a `LinearLayout`in your activities layout file and define the Id.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_id);

for(String s : BusRouteList){
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(s);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    linearLayout.addView(tv);
}
```

You can change the `LayoutParams` as you need.